# Ubuntu to disk from site for install

Tags: installation

I have an old Acer laptop with Windows 2000 running on it, no access to internet.  I would like to download Ubuntu to a DVD with my MacBook for installation on the Acer.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

go to

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

You need for sure a 32bit system - I would choose "long term support" LTS 12.04 for an older computer. When clicking next it will ask you to buy stuff just click on the left bottom of the page that you don't want and the download starts ;-)

the download is already an .iso file just burn the image to a cd/dvd or put it on a USB 
if you dont know how: check here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

then put the CD/DVD/USB, boot from it and follow the prompts

enjoy Ubuntu

PS: I would suggest internet connection for updates etc.